# Celery with Google Cloud MemoryStore for a Flask website

Tags: python, flask, celery, pymssql, google-cloud-memorystore

We are building a simple single-page website using flask to be deployed on GKE. In this , we have queries on MSSQL databases (used by another application) for which we want to use celery with Google cloud memorystore redis instance to run those queries scheduled once a day , then use that result data from queries on the website for that day as we do not want to query the databases everytime there is a visitor to the site (as the data is mostly static for a day).

Now , I am quite new to Software development and particularly DevOps less so. After reading up on resources online ,I couldn't much about it and I am still unsure about how this works .

Is The result data after completing the celery task stored in the Redis Result backend(Google cloud memorystore) in Google storage the entire day and can be accessed anytime in my Python code using celery task variable whenever a user visits the site ? Or should I access the data stored in Redis Result backend(GCM) in Google storage using another query to google cloud db in my code ? Or is the data stored in Redis Result backend(GCM) only temporary until the task is marked as Done and cannot be accessed throughout the day ? How do I move forward ? Can someone please point this out ?

Comment: If you're only hosting a single-page website, have you considered using instead Google App Engine and Cloud SQL? It would probably be a lot cheaper and simpler to implement.